# Query "must declare scalar variable"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have an error on my vb.net routine after executing the command, I get an error:

> must declare @nameD variable

The table in SQL Server is:

```
name: TAB,
ID integer unique,
NameD varchar(50)
```

I can't understand why I get this error.

Is it because I am using OLEdb on my local system? I am just converting a project to SQL Server or is there a mistake in the query?

Note that I use to open connection with those parameters:

```
Dim strsql As String = ""
Dim strConn As String = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=0.0.0.0;Database=****;UID=sa;PWD=***;"
Dim Conn As New OleDbConnection
```

and this is the function

```
Public Function Ins() as integer

     strsql = "INSERT INTO TAB (nameD) VALUES (@nameD)"

     Dim CMD as New OleDbCommand(strsql, Conn)

     With CMD
               .Parameters.Add("@nameD", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "aaa"
              .ExecuteNonQuery()
     End With

     CMD = Nothing

     Dim COnt As Long
     Dim cmdC As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT@@IDENTITY", Conn)
     COnt = CType(cmdC.ExecuteScalar, Integer)
     Return COnt
end function
```

I tried even with

```
CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameD", "aaa")
```

Comment: [OleDbParameter remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#remarks): "The OLE DB.NET Framework Data Provider uses positional parameters that are marked with a question mark (?) instead of named parameters."

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that it's supported using `OleDb` (it's not with Access but that may be a Jet/ACE thing) but, if you use `SqlClient`, you can do the `INSERT` and the `SELECT` in the same command with a single call to `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: It's not actually going to hurt but how exactly does it make sense to cast the result of your call to `ExecuteScalar` as type `Integer` and then assign it to a `Long` variable? That just shows a lack of thought.

Comment: yes, it was a question mark (?), i am migrating a project , it works

Comment: @jmcilhinney With Access and its OleDb providers, you can use named parameters (with `SELECT`, `INSERT`, whatever). The name is just ignored, the only thing that's considered in of course the position, related to the order in which the Parameters are added to the command.

Comment: @Jimi, you're not wrong but that's something that I was already aware of and it's not related to anything I said anyway. My reference to Access was in relation to the fact that you can't include multiple SQL statements in the one command. You can do that with `SqlClient` but I'm not sure whether it's a Jet/ACE thing or a common limitation of all OLE DB data sources.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Well, I wrote that because the only thing that I see mentioned here is the naming of parameters and you referred to Access (I cannot say with SQL Server + `MSOLEDBSQL` and generic OleDb, because I've never used it and I'm pretty sure I never will). -- I don't see the multiple statements in one command, there's an `INSERT` + `ExecuteNonQuery` and  `SELECT@@IDENTITY` + `ExecuteScalar` in another command. Are you referring to the weird *shared* connection or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jimi, my point was that you COULD use a single command to execute both SQL statements instead of using two separate commands as is being done here. It was an OT suggestion to improve the code, but I'm not sure that it's possible when using `OleDb`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ah, all right. I misinterpreted your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would use `OleDb` to connect to SQL Server rather than `SqlClient` but, if you're going to do so, I don't think that named parameters are supported. You need to use the generic parameter placeholder in your SQL code:

```vb
strsql = "INSERT INTO TAB (nameD) VALUES (?)"
```

Comment: yes, it was a question mark (?), i am migrating a project , it works